# How can I use getJSON and then run function response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Im trying to use getJSON and get all my elements from a jsonfile on a server, the problem I have is that i cant run the function $.each( response, function( key, val ) and i cant run  jsonObjects.push(val);
How can i run the function $.each( response, function( key, val ) and use jsonObjects.push(val);?

```
$.getJSON('http://192.168.8.143/api/v1.1/elements/', function(response) {

    console.log(response);

    $.each( response, function( key, val ) {

        jsonObjects.push(val);
    });
    populateT();
    populateI();
    loadPlanObject(currentFloor);
    populateName();
});
```

Comment: can you show response object?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: where and how jsonObjects is defined? or is it not defined at all?

Comment: @FUserThrowError Hi, this is the objects [{"e3014":{"name":"e3014","interval":15,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-06-26 19:40:27","type":"enddev"}},{"e3026":{"name":"e3026","interval":15,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-06-26 15:51:30","type":"enddev"}},{"R2500":{"name":"R2500","interval":1,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-11-28 14:03:20","type":null}},{"R2502":{"name":"R2502","interval":1,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-11-28 14:19:20","type":null}}]

Comment: Why do you need to loop over the response array and push the objects from that array into a new array? Seems redundant. `$.getJSON` returns parsed JSON already.

Comment: Does `console.log(response);` outputs something? If not, then you may need to implement an error function to `getJSON` to see detailed errors. Check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @Andy Hi, thats exactly what I wanna do, loop over the response array and push the objects from that array into a new array? When I run: console.log("Val " + val); and console.log("Key " + key);, the val is [object Object] and the key is 1, 2 and 3. I think the val is wrong?

Comment: @user3280126 Hi, If I run console.log(response); I get this in the console: [{"e3014":{"name":"e3014","interval":15,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-06-26 19:40:27","type":"enddev"}},{"e3026":{"name":"e3026","interval":15,"x":0,"y":0,"‌​plan":1,"added":"2013-06-26 15:51:30","type":"enddev"}},{"R2500":{"name":"R2500","interval":1,"x":0,"y":0,"p‌​lan":1,"added":"2013-11-28 14:03:20","type":null}},{"R2502":{"name":"R2502","interval":1,"x":0,"y":0,"plan"‌​:1,"added":"2013-11-28 14:19:20","type":null}}]

Comment: If I run this local code in a file called net.json there is no problem: "e3014":{"name":"e3014","interval":15,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-06-26 19:40:27","type":"enddev"},
"e3026":{"name":"e3026","interval":15,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-06-26 15:51:30","type":"enddev"},
"R2500":{"name":"R2500","interval":1,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-11-28 14:03:20","type":null},
"R2502":{"name":"R2502","interval":1,"x":0,"y":0,"plan":1,"added":"2013-11-28 14:19:20","type":null}

Comment: _"the val is [object Object]... I think the val is wrong"_: No, that is the output you should expect. Those are the JS objects from your parsed JSON data.